# Type = button, Onclick vs Onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple submit button and trying to trigger the click and submit event but both are not working...

html

```
<input type="submit" id="test">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').onclick(function(){
        alert('Hi')
})

    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert('Hi')
})

    $('#test').onclick(function(){
        alert('Hi')
})
})
```

fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/x57Lj/

Comment: submit event is not a "button" event but a "form" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem:*** the function `onclick()` does not exist in jQuery.

Simply replace `onclick()` with `click()`
Here is an example of your jsfiddle with not 1, but 2 event callbacks for 'click' :)

http://jsfiddle.net/x57Lj/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').click(function () {
        alert('Hi')
    })
    $('#test').click(function () {
        alert('Hi2')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean to use *jQuery's* [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
jQueryObject.on('click', handler);
```

The `onclick` property of *jQuery* objects is not the same as that on a *HTMLElement*, remember they're different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "on" and e.preventDefault(); to prevent page for reloading.

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Hi')
});
```

or:

```
$('#test').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Hi')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `click` function, not `onclick`. There is no `onclick` function in jQuery. `onclick` is an [HTML event attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) you use to wire up a DOM element to a pure javascript function.

So if using jQuery you want the following:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

which is equivalent to

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

in case you're wondering.

Comment: @Givi - They are called `HTML event attributes`, or `event attribute` for short, which is a kind of inline event handler.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I believe the comment was deleted

Answer (score 0):

Handle form submit with submit event. In case 'onclick' event it's not handle return button press.